# Remove everything before //

Tags: bash, sed

I have strings like `/mnt/c/BashTest/tmp/iostream` and `/mnt/c/BashTest/tmp//mnt/c/BashTest/tmp/iostream` and I need to check if there is `//` in the string and if it is, remove everything before `//` (except one `/`). For example `/mnt/c/BashTest/tmp/` from the second string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use a regex with GNU sed:

```
sed 's|.*//|/|' file
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

If the string is contained in a variable, you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ str=/mnt/c/BashTest/tmp//mnt/c/BashTest/tmp/iostream
$ echo "${str/*\/\//\/}"
/mnt/c/BashTest/tmp/iostream
```

It's a bit unwieldy because of `\/` escapes, but boils down to "replace the first instance of `*//` (everything up to and including `//`) by a single`/`".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try with `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=/)/.*' file
```